# How to format Events.StartDateTime in Salesforce EmailTemplate

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to format the startdatetime in an email template, but can't do. But i'm able to do the same with ActivityDate, but the problem is i don't get the time in ActivityDate.

Here's my code:
{!act.StartDateTime}

currently the date looks like Fri Aug 30 15:00:00 GMT 2013 
But I want to display this as 08/30/2013 11:00 AM (Eastern Time)

Any help would be appreciated!

Please note i'm trying to achieve this within email template

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> `{!act.StartDateTime +0}`

Or create formula field and display him instead of ActivityDate